# cant connect with secure connection to latest mysql server 8.0.36, error | MY-010914 | Server | Bad handshake

Tags: mysql-8.0, connectivity

I upgraded from MySQL server 7 to latest 8.0.36 and now when I try to connect securely using the following command:

```
mysql -u my_user -pxxxxxxxxx -h db-server.domain.com -P 3306 --verbose --protocol tcp --ssl-ca=db-server.domain.com.rootca.crt --ssl-cert=db-server.domain.com.crt --ssl-key=db-server.domain.com.key
```

...it is not working and I receive the following error:

> ERROR 2013 (HY000): Lost connection to MySQL server during query,

At the same time for server I get error:

> MY-010914  | Server    | Bad handshake.

Each time when I try to connect and I get "Bad handshake" error, the aborted connections variable is increased:

```
mysql> SHOW GLOBAL STATUS LIKE 'Aborted_connects';

| Variable_name    | Value |
|------------------|-------|
| Aborted_connects | 7     |


1 row in set (0.38 sec)

mysql>
```

However, it works when I write the command like this (not specifying the certificates):

```
mysql -u my_user -pXXXXXXXXXXXXX -h db-server.domain.com -P 3306 --verbose --protocol tcp
```

...then it works and connection properties are listed below:

```
mysql> \s
--------------
mysql  Ver 8.0.36 for Linux on x86_64 (MySQL Community Server - GPL)

Connection id:          25
Current database:
Current user:           my_user@db-server.domain.com
SSL:                    Cipher in use is TLS_AES_128_GCM_SHA256
Current pager:          stdout
Using outfile:          ''
Using delimiter:        ;
Server version:         8.0.36 MySQL Community Server - GPL
Protocol version:       10
Connection:              via TCP/IP
Server characterset:    utf8mb4
Db     characterset:    utf8mb4
Client characterset:    utf8mb4
Conn.  characterset:    utf8mb4
TCP port:               3306
Binary data as:         Hexadecimal
Uptime:                 1 hour 1 sec

Threads: 2  Questions: 406  Slow queries: 1  Opens: 570  Flush tables: 3  Open tables: 489  Queries per second avg: 0.112
--------------

mysql>
```

I tried also to capture the traffic using tcpdump, and then I see error:

> #08S01Bad handshake

How to solve this?

Why is there a "bad handshake" error?